# Sending POST data after validation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a little problem with sending post data after validation my form. It isn't working and I don't know why.

Here is my jQuery function for validation:

```
(function($,W,D)
{ 
var jquery = {};
jquery.UTIL =
{
    setupFormValidation: function()
    {
        $("#register").validate({ 

           rules: {
              -- rules--
            },
            messages: {
              -- messages--
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('register.php', $(form).serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
            form.submit();
            },'json');
            }
        });
    }
}
$(D).ready(function($) {
    jquery.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
});
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

So I just want to send data named: name, surname, email and password to php page. This is not my validation (I just found this one), so maybe its something wrong with it? I know that my code for sending post data should be inside `submitHandler`, but I have no idea how it should look in this situation.

Here is my form if someone will need it

```
 <form id="register" method="post" action="">  <br><br>
                <label for="name"></label><input placeholder="imię" type="text" name="name" id="name"> 
                <input placeholder="nazwisko" type="text" name="surname" id="surname"> 
                <input placeholder="e-mail" type="text" name="email" id="email">
                <input placeholder="hasło" type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
                <input placeholder="powtórz hasło" type="password" name="pass_confirm"     id="pass_confirm"> 
                <input type="submit" value="Załóż konto"/>
            </form>
```

Comment: Does your post work without validating it? What do you want to happen with the validation (do you want to send message to the user)? Have you installed the jQuery.validate plugin?

Comment: My validation is working correctly, all rules and messages are fine, I have all validate plugins included. I want that data in register.php so I can then input thme into variables like: $name=$_POST['name'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `submitHandler` is only used if you want to over-ride the default form action as per the plugin.

So in your code...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.post('register.php', $(form).serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
        form.submit();
    },'json');
}
```

I don't understand why you have `form.submit()` as part of the callback function within a `$.post()`.  The `$.post()` is ajax and the `form.submit()` is a standard form submission (plugin default).  My guess is that you are *blindly* following the horrifically bad jQuery4U tutorial.

If you just want to do the `ajax`, then all of your code can be condensed down into this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#register").validate({ 
        rules: {
            //-- rules--
        },
        messages: {
            //-- messages--
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'register.php',
                data:  $(form).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json'
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Otherwise, if you just want to do the standard form submit as per the `<form>` element's attributes, then you don't even need a `submitHandler` and all of your code can be condensed down into this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#register").validate({ 
        rules: {
            //-- rules--
        },
        messages: {
            //-- messages--
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you want your code to work, are you waiting for an AJAX call or do you want to send your form, in your code

```
$.post('register.php', $(form).serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
           form.submit();
        },'json');
```

This code is making an AJAX post request with JQuery JQuery post, the weird part of your code if that on the success function you're submitting the form.

So if you want to make an ajax call just be sure that you want to submit the form or what do you want to do after the call. If you just want to submit the form, instead of the ajax post, just send the form submit.

```
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `$.post()` in your `submitHandler` is uneccessary, just simply `$(form).submit()` should do the trick.